# Draw FabricJS shape with mouse

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am somewhat familiar with drawing shapes with the mouse but I want the shape to resize using FabricJS bottom right anchor. When a user presses mouse down a circle is created with radius 1. When the mouse is moved I would like the circle to resize using FabricJS anchor point.

```
'''
    // Circle
    document.getElementById('circle').addEventListener('click', function(){
        canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    
        // When mouse is pressed start circle
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
            
            // If an existing object is clicked, select that
            target = canvas.findTarget(o.e);
            if (target && target.selectable){
                canvas.setActiveObject(target);
                return;
          }
            pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
            x1 = pointer.x;
            y1 = pointer.y;
            circle = new fabric.Circle({
                radius: 1, stroke: stroke_color, left: x1, top: y1 
            })
            canvas.add(circle);
            canvas.setActiveObject(circle);
        })
    
        // When mouse is moved resize circle to pointer position
        canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
            // Get the mouse position and set bottom right anchor to it
            // TO DO
            canvas.renderAll();
          });
    
        // When mouse is released set shape coords
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
            circle.setCoords();
        })
    })
'''
```